# Logic Behind C Output

Tags: c

Why the output of following Program is

```
0 and Garbage Value and Garbage Value
```

Program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

int a=9,b=0,x,y;
x=a&b;
y=a||b;
printf("%d %d %d");
return 0;
}
```

Why the first time %d prints 0 ?

Comment: The output is NOT `"0 and Garbage Value and Garbage Value"`, it is, at best, `"Garbage Value and Garbage Value and Garbage Value"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code `printf("%d %d %d");` invokes Undefined Behavior

From section *7.19.6.1 The fprintf function* of the C99 standard:

> The fprintf function writes output to the stream pointed to by stream, under control of the string pointed to by format that specifies how subsequent arguments are converted for output. **If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.** If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored. The fprintf function returns when the end of the format string is encountered.

This behaviour also applies to the `printf()` function (and the `sprintf()` and `snprintf()` function).

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide arguments to the `printf` function, like this:

`printf("%d %d %d %d", a, b, x, y);`

If you don't provide values, the behaviour is *undefined*. This means it's non-repeatable. You're just getting random values from memory that are not guaranteed to be anything in particular.

Comment: I think the user is asking not how to use printf correctly but why the first output item is zero instead of garbage.

Comment: That is ok.My question is if not provide then why the answer is 0 and garbage.

Comment: @user3177233 - Because its Undefined Behavior hence anything can happen. You do reason out UBs.